# How to properly include a JSON string as an environment variable in Azure pipeline yaml file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following environment variable that I have included in my azure-pipelines.yaml file:

```
  - name: myVariable
    value: '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

The problem is the way that the pipeline is passing along this variable. When echoed, it looks like this: `key1:value1 key2:value2`, and since my application is expecting a JSON string, this is throwing JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end).

I tried formatting the variable differently with escape characters as follows:

`\{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"\}`

which resulted in this echoed variable as I would expect:

`{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`

but my application code threw this error JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes. I added double quotes as follows:

`"\{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key1\":\"value1\"\}"`

but then received the following error: While parsing a quoted scalar, find unknown escape character.

It seems like the pipeline file doesn't like the format of the variable. I'm wondering if there is an issue with the way that I have formatted the variable. I'd like for the variable to be passed the way I have described above, but if all else fails I could pass it in a more agreeable format and have my application code parse it. Would appreciate any thoughts, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this, it just follows your way of thinking of escaping everything? `\"\{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"\}\"`
Also is a good idea to share in what type of task you want to digest this JSON.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your application invokes the json. Check the variable [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables):

> Variables are always **strings**. If you want to use typed values, then you should use parameters instead.

you could use [convertToJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#converttojson) expression, it takes a complex object and outputs it as JSON.

```
parameters:
  - name: listOfValues
    type: object
    default:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2

steps:
- script: |
    echo "${MY_JSON}"
  env:
    MY_JSON: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.listOfValues) }}
```

output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you use it for variable:

```
variables:
  - name: myVariable
    value: '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'

steps:
- script: |
    echo "${newVar}" 
  env:
     newVar: ${{ convertToJson(variables.myVariable) }}
```

Output:

[image]

You could check to use parameter or variable for definition, and invoke `${MY_JSON}` in your application.